# Showing that a collection $B_Q$ is a basis for the metric topology on $\mathbb{R^{2}}$

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I am confused how to show this. Do I need to show that the union of a collection of basis $B_Q$ is the entire space (i.e. $\mathbb{R^{2}}$? Can someone help me solve this?

This is the way I did it, kindly check and let me know if this works. Also, suggest a better method to prove this theorem other than this.

[image]

Comment: You need to prove these satisfy the **definition** of a basis: (i) each set in $B_Q$ is open in the metric topology, (ii) each open set in the metric topology is a union of elements of $B_Q$.

Comment: how to show 1st one? I can still try to do the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1):

Show every open ball of the usual metric topology for R$^2$ is a union of sets of B$_Q$.

Thus the usual topology for R$^2$ is a subset of the topology generated by B$_Q$.

As B$_Q$ is a subset of all the open balls of the usual R$^2$, the topology generated by B$_Q$ is a subset of the usual topology for R$^2$.

Consequently those topologies are the same.

The proof that B$_Q$ is a base is just like the proof that the open balls of the usual topology is a base.
Certainly you have already discussed that.

Comment: I tried doing this but cant get it....I am stuck in some parts or areas while proving it. It would be better if you show me how to do this...